# \s doesn't actually capture all whitespace characters

Tags: java, regex, unicode, java-8

In my Java 8 app, I am scanning for whitespaces in text passed in. But `\s` in my Regular Expression doesn't capture all whitespaces. The one whitespace that I've found that it doesn't capture so far in my testing is [Non-breaking Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (Unicode 00A0). This was my regular expression that was running into that issue:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s");
```

To solve this, I added `\h` to my Regular Expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\s\\h]");
```

Now, are there any other whitespaces that I need to be aware of that wont be captured by `\s\h`?

Comment: `\v` would be one.

Comment: The easiest way to match all whitespace characters is `"\\p{Z}"`.  `Z` is a Unicode general category;  see http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values.

Comment: @VGR `\\p{Z}` does not match `\t` or `\n`.

Comment: @Holger Huh, you’re right.  I was sure they were included.  `\r` and `\u000b` aren’t included either.  They’re all classified as control characters.  So, I guess I would be using `"[\\s\\p{Z}]"`.  I think that covers everything…

Comment: @VGR or `\p{IsWhiteSpace}` or `(?U)\s`, as `\u000b`, `\r`, `\n`, and `\t` belong to the category “control” but have the binary property “white space”.

Comment: @Holger That is useful to know.  I had thought the White_Space binary property was essentially the same as the Z category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class documentation the characters that match `\s` are `\t\n\x0B\f\r`.

However, Unicode indeed supports a whole lot more [space characters](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=space). Examples include:

- `\u2002`: En space
- `\u2003`: Em space
- `\u2003`: Thin space
- `\u202F`: Narrow no-break space

Comment: From reading Pattern doc, and testing those space characters, it appears that `/v` would be the only additional whitespace matcher I would need to add to my regular expression. Thank you.

Comment: OK, so I copied every unicode character on that page that was blank (no marks) into a String, and was able to resolve them all with this Regex:

`Pattern.compile("(?:[\\s\\h\\v\\u2009\\u200B]|\\uDB40\\uDC20)*")`

Answer (score 10):

By default, `\s` only matches ASCII whitespace characters (`[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`). There are two ways to overcome this limitation

1. Use Unicode character properties: `Pattern.compile("\\p{IsWhiteSpace}")`
2. Make the predefined character class use Unicode properties:
   `Pattern.compile("\\s", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)`
   This can also be enabled via the embedded flag `(?U)`

```
Pattern[] pattern = {
    Pattern.compile("\\s"),
    Pattern.compile("\\s", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS),
    Pattern.compile("((?U)\\s)"),
    Pattern.compile("\\p{IsWhiteSpace}")
};
String s = " \t\n\u00A0\u2002\u2003\u2006\u202F";
for(Pattern p: pattern) {
    int count = 0;
    for(Matcher m = p.matcher(s); m.find(); ) count++;
    System.out.printf("%-19s: %d matches%n",
      p.pattern()+((p.flags()&Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)!=0? " [(?U) via flags]": ""),
      count);
}
```

```
\s                 : 3 matches
\s [(?U) via flags]: 8 matches
((?U)\s)           : 8 matches
\p{IsWhiteSpace}   : 8 matches
```

Answer (score 2):

We use `guava` for this...

```
String s = " \t\n\u00A0\u2002\u2003\u2006\u202F";
int b = CharMatcher.whitespace().countIn(s);
System.out.println(b); // 8
```