# Detecting whitespaces of fullwidth and halfwidth: regex VS Character.isWhitespace()

Tags: java, regex, string, java-8

My task is to detect if there is any whitespaces of string from csv of a server app. The content of CSV would be combinations of Japanese, English, some symbols and numerics. 
Whitespaces in English is halfwidth and that in Japanese is fullwidth. The width and byte sizes of whitespace in the 2 languages are different.

I am coding in Java 8 and not using 3rd parties libraries is preferable.

There are 2 approaches I am considering and these are pseudocodes.

Regex:

```
targetStr.matches("\\s+");
```

Character.isWhitespace():

```
targetStr.codepoints()
             .filter(c -> Character.isWhitespace(c))
             .count() > 0
```

Would any one of the above pseudocode do the task?

Which is more efficient for my case?

Comment: What is your problem statement now? What do you mean by full width and half width? Please post a minimal and reproducible example by following this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can reduce the second approach to `targetStr.codePoints().anyMatch(Character::isWhitespace)`.  It’s likely faster than a regular expression, but unless you’re executing it hundreds of times per second, you’re unlikely to notice the difference.

Comment: Are you trying to remove these whitespaces?

Comment: Actually I am trying to detect if there is any space in a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `targetStr.matches("\\s+")` and `targetStr.codepoints().filter(c -> Character.isWhitespace(c)).count() > 0` bear entirely different logic.

`String.matches` requires the entire string to match, so with `\s+` it has to consist of white-space entirely. In contrast, `count() > 0` is satisfied if you have at least one white-space character, so it’s an inefficient and verbose version of `targetStr.codepoints().anyMatch(Character::isWhitespace)`.

If you want to check whether all characters are white-space, you should use `allMatch` instead.

But further, there are different definitions of white-space

[`Character.isWhitespace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-int-):

> Determines if the specified character (Unicode code point) is
>    white space according to Java.  A character is a Java
>    whitespace character if and only if it satisfies one of the
>    following criteria:
>
> - It is a Unicode space character (`SPACE_SEPARATOR`,
>           `LINE_SEPARATOR`, or `PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR`)
>           but is not also a non-breaking space (`'\u00A0'`,
>           `'\u2007'`, `'\u202F'`).
>
>   It is `'\t'`, U+0009 HORIZONTAL TABULATION.
>
>   It is `'\n'`, U+000A LINE FEED.
>
>   It is `'\u000B'`, U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION.
>
>   It is `'\f'`, U+000C FORM FEED.
>
>   It is `'\r'`, U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN.
>
>   It is `'\u001C'`, U+001C FILE SEPARATOR.
>
>   It is `'\u001D'`, U+001D GROUP SEPARATOR.
>
>   It is `'\u001E'`, U+001E RECORD SEPARATOR.
>
>   It is `'\u001F'`, U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR.

[the `\s` pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef) (by default):

> `\s`   A whitespace character: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`

So there’s a significant difference.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56654027/2711488), you can make `\s` match all white-space characters or use a pattern that matches all unicode white-space characters in the first place. Or refer to the same logic as `Character.isWhitespace` explicitly, which is not exactly the same:

If you want to strictly apply the logic of `Character.isWhitespace`, you can use

- To match *all* characters

  - `string.codePoints().allMatch(Character::isWhitespace)`
  - `string.matches("\\p{javaWhitespace}+")`
  - `string.isBlank()` (JDK11)
- To match when there’s *at least* one white-space character

  - `string.codePoints().anyMatch(Character::isWhitespace)`
  - `string.matches(".*\\p{javaWhitespace}.*")`
  - `Pattern.compile("\\p{javaWhitespace}").matcher(string).find()`

As the first bullet of the `Character.isWhitespace` documentation states, it will return `false` for the non-breaking space characters (`'\u00A0'`, `'\u2007'`, `'\u202F'`), despite they have the white-space Unicode property. If you want to match them as white-space, you can use

- To match *all* characters

  - `string.matches("(?U)\\s+")`
  - `string.matches("\\p{IsWhiteSpace}+")`
- To match when there’s *at least* one white-space character

  - `string.matches("(?U).*\\s.*")`
  - `string.matches(".*\\p{IsWhiteSpace}.*")`
  - `Pattern.compile("\\p{IsWhitespace}").matcher(string).find()`
  - `Pattern.compile("\\s", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher(string).find()`