# Comparing two Strings with different types/lengths of whitespace using Java

Tags: java, json, string, string-comparison

I am trying to compare two strings in my program. One is sourced from a spreadsheet the other is sourced from a JSONArray.

```
JSONArray String: "Monday: 7:00 AM – 4:00 PM"
Spreadsheet String: "Monday: 7:00 AM – 4:00 PM"
```

Obviously they appear to be equal but when using `.equals()` it returns false. I suspect that the reason is that the JSON File (outputs a different length of whitespace than the spreadsheet. I was able to confirm this using a Diff checker (" " vs " ").

I have tried using `.replaceAll("\\s+"," ")` on both Strings but I am still getting a false result when I compare them.

Comment: In retrospect, the VTC should be to link to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56653323/s-doesnt-actually-capture-all-whitespace-characters - the 'weird whitespace' is, amongst other things, [NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm) - which `\\s` doesn't actually capture.

Comment: more generally you misunderstood `\\s`. `\\s` doesn't mean any whitespace. I know the tutorials say that, but they are all just plain wrong. It, specifically, refers __only__ to ASCII whitespace symbols: Tab, space, line break, and carriage return. Not things like no-break space and the like.